# Capture keypress / let user pick their own start/stop key

Tags: vb.net

Currently I have the start-key for my vb.net application hardcoded like this:

```
GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.F2)
```

Where vb.net sais "F2 As System.Windows.Forms.Keys = 113" on mouse-over

But I want my users to be able to pick their own Key. If I make a drop-down box (combobox) and pre-define some choices in there (Like ESC or F3), all those choices are strings. How can I convert those strings to a System.Windows.Forms.Keys integer?

Also, I'd like it to also be possible to "capture" a single keypress. So they'd click the "capture" button, and the next key they hit will be saved as the start/stop button. But I wouldn't even know where to begin looking for that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim captureKey As Boolean
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        captureKey = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_PreviewKeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PreviewKeyDownEventArgs) Handles Button1.PreviewKeyDown
        If captureKey Then
            Label1.Text = e.KeyValue.ToString
            captureKey = False
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

I created a form with a label and a button for an example. e.[KeyValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.previewkeydowneventargs.keyvalue.aspx) is an integer that I am converting to a string for display purposes. You also have the ability to capture other keydata. See this info on [PreviewKeyDownEventArg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.previewkeydowneventargs.aspx)

As for the first part of your question use a [Select Case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) Statement to convert between your ComboBox Values and KeyData Values.

Answer (score 2):

```
If txtKeys.Text=="F3" Then
GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.F3)
End If
```

Comment: It looks like you translated from C# == is not valid and you also need a Then i.e. If txtKeys.Text = "F3" Then ...